# How do I use videojs playlist?

Tags: video.js

How do I install the video js playlist plug-in? In the example they ask for this file: `path/to/videojs-playlist/dist/videojs-playlist.js`, but I don't find a dist folder or the .js file. Clues? I have the video.js file. Thanks!

https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist

Comment: So just use the js file

Comment: I'm looking for the `videojs-playlist.js` file

Comment: You said you had the js file

Comment: I have the `video.js` file, not the plug-in `videojs-playlist.js`. See the link I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Installing NodeJS**

Multiple installers are available on their download page. 
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node

**Using Npm install**

This command installs a package, and any packages that it depends on. It reads the file `package.json` and installs what ever dependency it requires.

It should install all the files you require to run `videojs-playlist`

After installing simply execute the following command in your `videojs-playlist` project folder.

`npm install videojs-playlist`

Comment: Can I reach the .js file directly somewhere? I'm new to this and have never used nodeJS or npm.

Comment: Maybe there are some example files, where your plugin files are used?

Comment: But do I need this NodeJS to even run it anyway? The example looks like normal js file include, but I can't find that file anywhere.

Comment: Wonderful! Not sure why the dist can't be available without installing, but it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Glad i could help!